# Python - Write Raster with gdal

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I want to write a raster with `gdal` within a function.

```
def WriteRaster(InputArray, OutputFile, NROWS, NCOLS, XULCorner, YULCorner, Cellsize, wkt_projection):
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
dataset = driver.Create("%s", NROWS, NCOLS, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32 %(OutputFile))
dataset.SetGeoTransform((XULCorner,Cellsize,0,YULCorner,0,-Cellsize))
dataset.SetProjection(wkt_projection)
dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(InputArray)
dataset.FlushCache()
return None
```

I get this error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'

I thought I could define the output filename this way. Why not?

Thanks for helping!!!

Comment: Give us a hint which line that error ocurrs on?

Comment: The error occurs when I want to define the output files name

dataset = driver.Create("%s", NROWS, NCOLS, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32 %(OutputFile))

Comment: Yeah gdal.GDT_Float32 %(OutputFile) doesn't make a lot of sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that line:

```
dataset = driver.Create("%s", NROWS, NCOLS, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32 %(OutputFile))
```

should be something more like:

```
dataset = driver.Create("%s"%(OutputFile), NROWS, NCOLS, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32 )
```

see I moved the %(OutputFile) bit?

Although, if OutputFIle is a string, you could use:

```
dataset = driver.Create(OutputFile, NROWS, NCOLS, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32 )
```

See https://pyformat.info/ for some more info about format strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Works fine now